# python nonetype between int and none type

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

what's problem with my code ?Can any body helpme??
While I'm trying to perform addition operation on the follwing code I'm getting error that

1. **unsupported type operands 'None type' and 'int'** and
2. **maximum stack depth exceeded**  after 4 iterations

Is there any alternate solution to solve **ackermanns** problem? 
Here is y code

```
tcase=6
sum=0

def a(m,n):
   m=m
   n=n
   if m==0:
       return n+1
   elif m>0 and n==0:
       return a(m-1,1) 
   elif m>0 and n>0:
       return a(m-1,a(m,n-1))


for i in range(0,(tcase+1)):
   sum+=a(i,i)
   print sum
```

**QUESTION** How to implement Ackerman function with more efficiency?

Comment: "No Body" can help you until you tell us what your problem is!

Comment: It gives me error :unsupported operand types for + for 'None Type' AND 'int'

Comment: That's not [the error I get](http://ideone.com/s2ZYtt). Are you absolutely sure that the code you've posted here is the code that's producing the error you're seeing?

Comment: Yes , Why I'm getting that error

Comment: I believe you're getting that error. I suspect you're actually running an older version of your script, perhaps because you forgot to save your most recent draft, or because you're executing a script that has the same name but is in a different directory. If you copy-paste your code into an online interpreter such as http://ideone.com, what error message will you see?

Comment: I'm getting **runtime**  error after fourth iteration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to implement the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), which is famous for returning really really ridiculously huge numbers for small inputs.

You're getting a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error when you execute `a(4,4)`, because a(4,4) is equal to `2^(2^(2^65536)))`, and calculating it would require more stack space than your computer (or any existing computer) could possibly have capacity for.